# QtMultimedia - QAudioDecoder - Python - state changes, but buffer never made available

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I hate to say how long it took me to get to this point but I had real trouble completely understanding PyQt5 and how it relates to the C++ code I was seeing on the Qt website but I think .. I get it, or... at least I thought I did until this completely failed to work.  I'll start with the output I'm getting, that tells me I have a file that really exists.  I've tried mp3 and ogg version in case for some reason AudioDecoder can't decode the MP3 even though other parts of QtMultimedia have been able to play it (I'm trying to get lower level so I can apply panning to the audio and shift the left/right balance, and maybe other fun things once I figure that out).

Debug output:

```
MP3 exists:True
Decoder stopped:True <- expected at this point, just confirming state works 
Decoder state changed? <- this means state change signal is being sent
Decoder stopped?:False <- ok, state did actually change, that's expected
Decoder decoding?:True <- expected, confirming there are only 2 states as documentation indicates 
Init finished, Decoder started? <- after this, i expect to see position changes, buffer availability changes, or errors ... but I get nothing and it just exits the script.
```

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio

class AudioDecoder(QObject):  
  def __init__(self):
    super(AudioDecoder,self).__init__()
    self.desiredFormat = QAudioFormat()
    self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(2)
    self.desiredFormat.setCodec('audio/pcm')
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(48000)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)

    self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()
    self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
    self.decoder.setSourceFilename('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')
    fs = QFileInfo()
    print('MP3 exists:' + str(fs.exists('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')))

    #self.connect(decoder,bufferReady(),None,readBuffer())
    self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer)
    self.decoder.finished.connect(self.play)
    self.decoder.error.connect(self.error)
    self.decoder.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)
    self.decoder.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
    self.decoder.bufferAvailableChanged.connect(self.bufferAvailableChanged)

    #using this to determine if we need to start byte array or append to it
    self.readamount = 0 

    #Expect this to be true since we haven't started yet 
    print('Decoder stopped:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))    
    self.decoder.start()
    print('Init finished, Decoder started?')
  def bufferAvailableChanged(self):
   print(str(decoder.available))
  def positionChanged(self):
    print(str(decoder.position())+'/'+str(decoder.duration))
  def stateChanged(self):
    #Confirm state is what we expect
    print('Decoder state changed?')
    print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))
    print('Decoder decoding?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.DecodingState))
  def error(self):
    print('Decoder error?')
    print(self.decoder.errorString())
  def readBuffer(self):
    print('Decoder ready for reading?')
    buffer = self.decoder.read()
    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(buffer.byteCount))
    if self.readamount == 0:
      self.ba = QByteArray()
      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
    else:
      self.ba.append(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
    print('Bytearray size:' + str(self.ba.length()))  
  def play(self):
    print('Decoding finished, ready to play')

ad = AudioDecoder()
```

Revised code, attempting WAV, still not working though:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtTest import QSignalSpy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio

class AudioDecoder(QObject):  
  def __init__(self):
    super(AudioDecoder,self).__init__()
    self.desiredFormat = QAudioFormat()
    self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(2)
    self.desiredFormat.setCodec('audio/pcm')
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(48000)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)

    self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()

    self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer)
    self.decoder.finished.connect(self.play)
    self.decoder.error.connect(lambda: self.error(self.decoder.error()))
    self.decoder.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.stateChanged(self.decoder.state()))
    self.decoder.positionChanged.connect(lambda: self.positionChanged(self.decoder.position(),self.decoder.duration()))
    self.decoder.bufferAvailableChanged.connect(lambda: self.bufferAvailableChanged(self.decoder.available()))

    self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
    self.decoder.setSourceFilename('D:\\python\\sounds\\piano2.wav')
    fs = QFileInfo()
    print('File exists:' + str(fs.exists('D:\\python\\sounds\\piano2.wav')))

    #using this to determine if we need to start byte array or append to it
    self.readamount = 0 

    #Expect this to be true since we haven't started yet 
    print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))    
    self.decoder.start()      
    print('Init finished, Decoder started on file:' + self.decoder.sourceFilename())    
  @pyqtSlot()
  def bufferAvailableChanged(self,available):
   print('Available:' + str(available))
  @pyqtSlot() 
  def positionChanged(self,position,duration):
    print('Position:' + str(position())+'/'+str(duration()))  
  @pyqtSlot()   
  def stateChanged(self,state):
    #Confirm state is what we expect
    print('Decoder state changed')
    if state == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState:
      print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(state == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))
    else:
      print('Decoder decoding?:' + str(state == QAudioDecoder.DecodingState))    
  @pyqtSlot()  
  def error(self,err):
    print('Decoder error')
    print(self.decoder.errorString())  
  def readBuffer(self):
    print('Decoder ready for reading?')
    buffer = self.decoder.read()
    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(buffer.byteCount))
    if self.readamount == 0:
      self.ba = QByteArray()
      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
    else:
      self.ba.append(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
    self.readamount = self.readamount + 1
    print('Bytearray size:' + str(self.ba.length()))      
  def play(self):
    print('Decoding finished, ready to play')

ad = AudioDecoder()
```

My update code post answer from below, and it works with mp3 :)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtTest import QSignalSpy
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio
import signal

class AudioDecoder(QObject):  
  def __init__(self):
    super(AudioDecoder,self).__init__()
    self.desiredFormat = QAudioFormat()
    self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(2)
    self.desiredFormat.setCodec('audio/pcm')
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(48000)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)

    self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()

    self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer)
    self.decoder.finished.connect(self.play)
    self.decoder.error.connect(self.error)
    self.decoder.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)
    self.decoder.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
    self.decoder.bufferAvailableChanged.connect(self.bufferAvailableChanged)

    self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
    self.decoder.setSourceFilename('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')
    fs = QFileInfo()
    print('File exists:' + str(fs.exists('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')))

    #using this to determine if we need to start byte array or append to it
    self.readamount = 0 

    #Expect this to be true since we haven't started yet 
    print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))    
    self.decoder.start()      
    print('Init finished, Decoder started on file:' + self.decoder.sourceFilename())      
  def bufferAvailableChanged(self,available):
   print('Available:' + str(available))  
  def positionChanged(self,position):
    print('Position:' + str(position)+'/'+str(self.decoder.duration))     
  def stateChanged(self,state):
    #Confirm state is what we expect
    print('Decoder state changed')
    if state == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState:
      print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(state == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))
    else:
      print('Decoder decoding?:' + str(state == QAudioDecoder.DecodingState))      
  def error(self,err):
    print('Decoder error')
    print(self.decoder.errorString())  
  def readBuffer(self):
    print('Decoder ready for reading?')
    buffer = self.decoder.read()
    byteCount = buffer.byteCount()
    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(byteCount))
    if self.readamount == 0:
      self.ba = QByteArray()
      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.constData().asstring(byteCount))
    else:
      self.ba.append(buffer.constData().asstring(byteCount))
    self.readamount = self.readamount + 1
    print('Bytearray size:' + str(self.ba.length()))      
  def play(self):
    print('Decoding finished, ready to play')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])    
ad = AudioDecoder()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_DFL)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: *I've noticed a couple missing things in above code, nothing that should cause the result I'm getting, but stuff that would result in unexpected behavior.  I forgot to update readamount after reading for example, and I noticed that I can avoid having to call decoder.state in connected python slot if I put state in the function call, but that didn't change the behavior, even if it's cleaner than above.

Comment: After fixing a lot of minor errors in the code, I was able to get it to work okay. I only tested on linux, though (which uses the gstreamer backend). You might want to try with a `wav` file, as that format is guaranteed to be supported.

Comment: I did try it with a wav file later on, also after trying some adjustments (will put them below).  Would you mind putting an answer here with the minor adjustments you made to the code?

Comment: I suspect I'm missing something basic you are seeing that I'm not, because otherwise this is just a linux vs windows issue, but I don't know why that would be.  I'll see if I can get a VM setup to test that.

Comment: I've added an answer. I suspect it might not help much, but you never know ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my (Linux) working version of your original script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio

class AudioDecoder(QObject):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AudioDecoder,self).__init__()
    self.desiredFormat = QAudioFormat()
    self.desiredFormat.setChannelCount(2)
    self.desiredFormat.setCodec('audio/pcm')
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleRate(48000)
    self.desiredFormat.setSampleSize(16)

    self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()
    self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
    fs = QFileInfo('test.wav')
    self.decoder.setSourceFilename(fs.absoluteFilePath())
    print('File exists:' + str(fs.exists()))

    #self.connect(decoder,bufferReady(),None,readBuffer())
    self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer)
    self.decoder.finished.connect(self.play)
    self.decoder.error.connect(self.error)
    self.decoder.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged)
    self.decoder.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
    self.decoder.bufferAvailableChanged.connect(self.bufferAvailableChanged)

    #using this to determine if we need to start byte array or append to it
    self.readamount = 0

    #Expect this to be true since we haven't started yet
    print('Decoder stopped:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))
    self.decoder.start()
    print('Init finished, Decoder started?')
  def bufferAvailableChanged(self):
   print(str(self.decoder.bufferAvailable()))
  def positionChanged(self):
    print(str(self.decoder.position())+'/'+str(self.decoder.duration()))
  def stateChanged(self):
    #Confirm state is what we expect
    print('Decoder state changed?')
    print('Decoder stopped?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.StoppedState))
    print('Decoder decoding?:' + str(self.decoder.state() == QAudioDecoder.DecodingState))
  def error(self):
    print('Decoder error?')
    print(self.decoder.errorString())
  def readBuffer(self):
    print('Decoder ready for reading?')
    buffer = self.decoder.read()
    count = buffer.byteCount()
    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(count))
    if self.readamount == 0:
      self.ba = QByteArray()
      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.constData().asstring(count))
      self.readamount = count
    else:
      self.ba.append(buffer.constData().asstring(count))
    print('Bytearray size:' + str(self.ba.length()))
  def play(self):
    print('Decoding finished, ready to play')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])
ad = AudioDecoder()

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
# press Ctrl+C to exit

app.exec_()
```

Diff:

```
--- yours
+++ mine
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia
 from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QIODevice, QFileInfo
 from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDecoder, QAudioFormat, QMediaObject, QAudioBuffer, QAudioOutput, QAudio
@@ -14,9 +15,9 @@

     self.decoder = QAudioDecoder()
     self.decoder.setAudioFormat(self.desiredFormat)
-    self.decoder.setSourceFilename('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')
-    fs = QFileInfo()
-    print('MP3 exists:' + str(fs.exists('D:\\python\\sounds\\30.mp3')))
+    fs = QFileInfo('test.wav')
+    self.decoder.setSourceFilename(fs.absoluteFilePath())
+    print('File exists:' + str(fs.exists()))

     #self.connect(decoder,bufferReady(),None,readBuffer())
     self.decoder.bufferReady.connect(self.readBuffer)
@@ -34,9 +35,9 @@
     self.decoder.start()
     print('Init finished, Decoder started?')
   def bufferAvailableChanged(self):
-   print(str(decoder.available))
+   print(str(self.decoder.bufferAvailable()))
   def positionChanged(self):
-    print(str(decoder.position())+'/'+str(decoder.duration))
+    print(str(self.decoder.position())+'/'+str(self.decoder.duration()))
   def stateChanged(self):
     #Confirm state is what we expect
     print('Decoder state changed?')
@@ -48,14 +49,23 @@
   def readBuffer(self):
     print('Decoder ready for reading?')
     buffer = self.decoder.read()
-    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(buffer.byteCount))
+    count = buffer.byteCount()
+    print('Bytecount in buffer:' + str(count))
     if self.readamount == 0:
       self.ba = QByteArray()
-      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
+      self.ba.fromRawData(buffer.constData().asstring(count))
+      self.readamount = count
     else:
-      self.ba.append(buffer.data(),buffer.byteCount())
+      self.ba.append(buffer.constData().asstring(count))
     print('Bytearray size:' + str(self.ba.length()))
   def play(self):
     print('Decoding finished, ready to play')

+app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])
 ad = AudioDecoder()
+
+import signal
+signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
+# press Ctrl+C to exit
+
+app.exec_()
```

Output:

```
File exists:True
Decoder stopped:True
Init finished, Decoder started?
Decoder state changed?
Decoder stopped?:False
Decoder decoding?:True
True
Decoder ready for reading?
0/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:0
Decoder ready for reading?
40/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:7680
Decoder ready for reading?
80/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:15360
Decoder ready for reading?
120/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:23040
Decoder ready for reading?
False
160/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:30720
...

Bytecount in buffer:7680
Bytearray size:37662720
Decoder ready for reading?
False
196200/196238
Bytecount in buffer:7364
Bytearray size:37670084
Decoding finished, ready to play
Decoder state changed?
Decoder stopped?:True
Decoder decoding?:False
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to read-up a little to understand some of the differences in what you did, but I mostly get what the problem was.  The reason everything wasn't advancing along seems to have to do with the fact I didn't have your QtWidgets.QApplication object and execute I guess what one might call the "application loop".   I had seen some python libraries that required it and some that didn't and I didn't know why they did when they did, but I think I understand this now.  All this signal/slot stuff doesn't necessarily happen unless the main app loop object is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was tremendously helpful. I know I need to pay a lot more attention to the whole application loop with all these different libraries. Once I added that I started getting errors and the rest of your changes dropped in perfectly to fix those.  If I recall from reading elsewhere, the purpose of the signal.signal line is to allow me to still be able to terminate application loop with ctrl + C?

Comment: @MatthewSwaringen. Ah - I did wonder about the lack of an app object, but just assumed your example was part of a more complete script. The signal-slot framework is separate from the events framework, so it often doesn't require a running event-loop. Some significant exceptions to that are timers and threads, though, since they need to be asynchronous. I guess the multimedia classes might use timers and threads quite extensively.

Comment: PS: yes, `signal.signal` can be quite handy for testing applications that don't have a gui. Without a window to close, the event-loop will just sit there spinning forever.

Comment: Nothing complex yet, just learning one piece at a time.  I just need to make sure I don't accidentally toss out pieces that I don't fully understand why I need them ... because maybe I need them and just don't know why yet.  Thanks for the explanation for why the event loop is probably needed.  Asynchronicity is something I want eventually, since my goal is to play multiple tracks at the same time.

Comment: I tested the updated script in windows and kubuntu (since you mentioned using linux I set it up on a VM). In windows it took a surprisingly long time to decode the file.  In kubuntu it is significantly faster (1/4 time).  Given kubuntu is on a VM it should not be faster at all, so I'm a little confused by this.  Something new to look into :)